# Introductory biology text for an outsider

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm a maths major and I have an interest in learning biology. I know very, very little; I know how babies are made and that's about it. Could anyone recommend a stimulating text to read for its own sake and also to use to learn biology?

Comment: What aspect of biology do you wish to learn? (Human biology, plant biology or Zoology? I'm guessing you are interested in human biology from your e-mail). For example are you looking to explore mathematical applications within biology?-e.g. mathematical biology or you just want to study biology in your leisure.

Comment: I'm being deliberately vague here; I just want very basic biology and not specific at all. I am deliberately NOT looking for a mathematical perspective, however I would like a generally insightful and interesting view on the topic.

Comment: I think Helena Curtis Biology is a quite interesting book. It was written many years ago and so does not involve really recent research but it is really insightful. Another book I would recommend is Campbell - it is both recently written and thought provoking. You should also read magazines like Scientific American to get insight into latest happenings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the Campbell Biology textbook to be quite comprehensive and approachable. I think many introductory biology courses use it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Campbell-Biology-Edition-Jane-Reece/dp/0321558235](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321558235)

Comment: Yes.  This one. By the time I graduated, I think I had 4 editions.

Answer (score 7):

There are tons of books and it is quite hard to find one that gives such a broad overview. [Campbell Biology](https://www.amazon.ca/Campbell-Biology-9th-Jane-Reece/dp/0321558235/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1513808241&sr=8-2&keywords=campbell+biology) is a book that basically covered the first year of my Bachelor degree in biology. I am not sure it would be very stimulating though! If there is a specific branch of biology that interests you, let us know we'll be able to give you a better advice.

As a math Major you might enjoy some fields of biology that are highly mathematized. For example, system biology or theoretical evolutionary biology. For the latter, you might like to read [Evolutionary Dynamics: Exploring the Equations of Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674023382) book from Martin Nowak. But I am afraid it might not be a nice idea to directly jump into some specific subject before having a good overview of the life sciences.

Otherwise you might appreciate some books of popular (but good level) science such as [the Extended Phenotype](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192880519) from Richard Dawkins. This book is very stimulating and I think it starts with some basic definitions of biological concepts such those of "alleles" or "phenotype".

I gave you two examples of books from the field of theoretical evolutionary biology. For more recommendations in this field, please have a look at [Books on population or evolutionary genetics?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/books-on-population-or-evolutionary-genetics).

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Could you list the book title that you linked to?  The link is now dead but I'd be interested in checking out the book.

Comment: @Addem Thanks for highlighting my broken links. It was a link for the Campbell. The same one as suggested in xuanji's answer. See edit.

Answer (score 4):

You should check out Richard Dawkins' book The *Greatest Show on Earth: The Evidence for Evolution*

It does focus heavily on evolution but it is an amazing book on biology in general.  He covers a wide rage of other topics, from how birds flock so elegantly to dating fossils using dendrochronology.  The chapter on embryology is fascinating.

Answer (score 2):

@xuanji offers a good choice with [*Campbell* Biology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321775651)  if you want a text solid biology textbook. I've got a copy in my library. I would suggest buying a previous edition if you're trying to save money. However, the book could be a bit dry. Reading semi-popular books on topics you are interested about would probably be better approach.

Both @ebrohman and @Remi.b provide good suggestions with Dawkins. I also like Ernst Mayr's [*What is evolution*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465044263) on the topic of evolution.

For ecology, check out books by [E.O. Wilson](http://www.amazon.com/Edward-O.-Wilson/e/B000AQ4776/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1430063182&sr=1-1) or [Jared Diamond](http://www.amazon.com/Jared-Diamond/e/B000AQ01ZS/ref=sr_tc_2_0?qid=1430063228&sr=1-2-ent).

If you want to learn more about environmental toxicology, Rachel Carson's [*Silent Spring*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618249060) is a good book to start off with.

If you're looking for a mathematical biology book, Linda Allen has two biomath text books, one on [deterministic models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130352160) the other on [stochastic models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439818827). Murry's also produced some classical mathematical biology [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952233). Most people would consider these books dry, but as a mathematician, you might like them.

James Watson can be controversial but he's written some interesting books. His [*Double Helix*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/074321630X) is a good read.

If you provide what specific type of biology and mathematics you are interested in, I will provide more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible of biology is the Alberts' Molecular Biology of the Cell:

> http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21054/

The Campbell is also pretty good and maybe easier to read..

Comment: Campell would provide a better overview if the OP wants to learn about more than molecular biology.