# books for beginners in research in mathematical biology

Tags: book-recommendation

I am a M.SC(mathematics) student. I have no subject like mathematically modelling.But  i'm interesting in research in mathematical biology.Initially which book i should study.
Please guide me.THANKS...

Comment: This is far too broad to answer effectively.  We don't know anything about which specific areas you are interested in or what your level of ability is, aside from that you haven't had any mathematical modeling coursework.  Most books would probably be accessible for someone with a background in ODEs, and I'm sure you've had experience with those.

Comment: additional info is needed for sure. Everything can be mathematically modeled.

Comment: Beside the Otto & Day book, also consider [Murray's *Mathematical Biology: I. An Introduction*](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Biology-Introduction-Interdisciplinary-Mathematics/dp/0387952233) (also [*Mathematical Biology II: Spatial and Biomedical Applications*](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Biology-Applications-Interdisciplinary-Mathematics/dp/0387952284/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1426250626&sr=1-1-fkmr0&keywords=athematical+Biology+II%3A+Spatial+Models+and+Biomedical+Applications)). It covers different applications and is written for people coming from a math background.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best contemporary book taking a broad view of mathematical biology modeling is [Otto and Day's](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8458.html) 2007 book *A Biologist's Guide to Mathematical Modeling in Ecology and Evolution* published by Princeton University Press.

There are also a number of books that focus on more specific areas e.g. mathematical population genetics, ecological modeling, infectious disease epidemiology, etc. But without knowing which areas of modeling interest you it is difficult to recommend at this level.

Comment: sorry for too late comment ...i'm interesting in mathematical population genetics

Answer (score 0):

The post is too broad. Mathematics is used in tons of different fields of biology.

Population genetics is one of the main field of biology that is contains quite a lot of mathematical formulations. [This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/book-recommendation-on-population-evolutionary-genetics) gives a list of references for books in population genetics.

Comment: was this perhaps intended to be a comment?

Comment: You are right. It should have been a comment. Too late to add comments though.