# Mathematical modelling of omics data

Tags: genomics, mathematical-models, metabolomics

I'm interested in modelling host-pathogen interactions using mathematics. I know there are good resources in Pubmed but seems I'm looking for a book or introductory reviews.

My background in maths is limited, knowing the basics about calculus and algebra, and more recently some machine learning.

The paper inspiring this question is this one:

Front Microbiol. 2015; 6: 235.
A review on computational systems biology of pathogen–host interactionsA review on computational systems biology of pathogen–host interactions

Comment: Why negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused because your title and your question description don't seem to align perfectly (-omics data versus host-pathogen interactions). If you are interested in host-pathogen dynamics, in my opinion, the best general introductory text in this area is Keeling and Rohani [Modeling infectious diseases and humans and animals](http://www.modelinginfectiousdiseases.org/).

Comment: The paper I posted in the question reflects what I'm trying to ask. I'm interested in studying host-pathogen interactions from an omics perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As @Corvus said before me, the core of your post talks about mathematical modelling of host-pathogen interactions. The title talks about analyzing omics data. What are you really interested in? I will assume you are interested in modelling of host-pathogen interactions (as @Corvus did).

I agree with @Corvus (+1) that [Modeling infectious diseases and humans and animals](http://www.modelinginfectiousdiseases.org/) is a good book to understand host-pathogen dynamics.

If you feel a bit uneasy about mathematical modelling, I strongly recommend [A guide to mathematical modelling in ecology and evolution](http://www.amazon.ca/Biologists-Mathematical-Modeling-Ecology-Evolution/dp/0691123446).

Aside those recommendations, [Evolutionary dynamics](http://www.amazon.ca/Evolutionary-Dynamics-Exploring-Equations-Life/dp/0674023382) might interest you to understand evolution of viruses including evolution of virulence. Finally you might appreciate [why we get sick](http://www.amazon.ca/Why-We-Get-Sick-Darwinian-ebook/dp/B006XWYJSI/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1431359358&sr=1-1&keywords=why%20we%20get%20sick) although it is not heavy on math and a bit outdated.

In case you are interested, you will find on [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/book-recommendation-on-population-evolutionary-genetics/16474#16474) book recommendations for theoretical population genetics.