# Where can I find a file listing the genetic differences in humans?

Tags: dna-sequencing, genomes, human-genome

I don't know much about genetics. For an arts project I'm looking for a human genome.

I read that:

> Only about 0.1% of the genome is different among individuals, which equates to about 3 million variants (aka mutations) in the average human genome. This means we can make a “diff file” of just the places where any given individual differs from the normal “reference” genome. In practice, this is usually done in a .VCF file format, which in its simplest format looks something like so:
>
> chr20 14370 rs6054257 G A 29 PASS 0|0
>
> Where each line uses ~45 bytes, and you times this by the ~3 million variants in a given genome, and you get a .VCF file size of about 135,000,000 bytes or ~125 megabytes.

Is that correct?

Do you know a database to download a VCF file or something similar? It would be amazing if you could provide a link to the file mentioned above!

Comment: You may need to rethink your number, that 0.1% number might be a little low... If you are interested in the genetics, you may be interested in this answer, http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/41975/16651. Also, NCBI's databases are open to the public and you should be able to download whatever you want from them.

Comment: Technically speaking (and in [SI and IEC terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)) 135,000,000 is 135 Megabytes (MB) or approximately 129 Mebibytes (MiB).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried poking around the 1000 genomes project?

Try this link

ftp://ftp.1000genomes.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/ftp/pilot_data/release/2010_07/exon/snps/