# Why do I have 95% of chimpanzee's DNA, and only 2% of Neanderthal's DNA?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics

Excuse me if it is a question with a simply answer, but I don't understand these discoveries, looking a discrepancy from my unknowledge of genetics:

- [I have 95% of Chimapanzee's DNA](https://www.pnas.org/content/99/21/13633.short),

and,

- [I have [only] 2% of Neanderthal's DNA](https://genographic.nationalgeographic.com/neanderthal/).

Neanderthals should had also chimapnzee genes, so what does that 2% of  correspondency between Neanderthal and actual Homo sapiens genome exactly means?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/how-many-genes-do-we-share-with-our-mother https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41974/why-are-the-genomes-of-humans-99-5-the-same https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61147/neanderthal-human-genetics

Comment: Some version of this question has been asked and answered several times... I thought we had a more clear canonical answer but maybe I'm just thinking of the first in my list.

Comment: Also https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/do-apes-and-humans-share-99-of-dna-or-99-of-genes-what-is-the-difference

Comment: @Bryan Krause thanks. So we share 95% of DNA with chimpanzees, but 2% of genes with Neanderthal. Genes are formed using only 5% of simple letters of DNA sequence. That's what I understand. And that 2% is what? Don't we have a bigger correspondence with Neanderthal genes than 2%? I still missunderstand it.

Comment: Can you excuse me and add a comment if closed? I have personal interest because I have asperger disorder related with neanderthal genome, and I don't undesrtand english very well (and a bit of dislexis).

Comment: This all a question of what is meant by “share % of our DNA”, which is obviously different in the two cases. My “todo” list includes writing a definitive answer to all the questions that result from loose journalistic language in this area. Alas, I have not yet found the time. Your response to @BryanKrause illustrates the confusion: you are using %DNA and %genes as if they were equivalent. They are not. And what do you mean by %genes? Not what the 2% means, I bet.

Comment: Probably iayork's answer here (also linked above): https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61147/neanderthal-human-genetics is the most succinct way to put it without deeper explanation.

Comment: My interest grew when I read they created micro brains with neanderthal DNA. But that's totaly out of my knowledge. Just I felt a bit more Neanderthal as asperger, after reading: "neural structure developed unusually, mirroring some of the developmental differences seen in people with autism"  http://discovermagazine.com/2019/january/ancient-brains

Comment: @Bryan Krause I contribute to marck it as duplicate. Personaly I learned the comprehension mistake I had and I learned DNA is not the same as genome. However I still don't understand what's my 2% genome correspondance with neanderthals Max Plank Institute published. I guess it takes in consider variations of N that were transmited to sapiens. It should be a result calc to determine % of ancestors we have/tax of specie mixing. Maybe I could reformulate my question but I am studing exams for a public job on gov. Maybe in some months. Ty!

Comment: @Universal_learner The 2% is referring to alleles that were A) Absent from homo sapiens at one point, B) Present in neanderthals, C) Present in present-day homo sapiens due to breeding between humans and neanderthals. It omits alleles shared in both. Also beware of the ASD/neanderthal linkage, it is not a scientifically supported theory to my knowledge.

Comment: @Bryan Krause thanks, I understand. So it is a kind of tax of intrusion of Neandertal pool, being the total pool the actual human genome (not DNA).

Comment: I find it a confusing data. That doesn't mean at all I have a 2% of Neanderthal genome neither (I have 2% of exclusive neanderthal genome). And also, I thougth my neanderthal pool as asperger/autist was very similar to other humans, that 2%, afecting in my case on nervous system (the difference); but maybe in my case is 5% who knows, I haven't sent a sample to max planck institute with my genome.