# Book recommendation: Modern Synthetic theory

Tags: evolution, book-recommendation

I'm a zoology minor. I wish to study modern synthetic theory (evolution) is there a good book available online for reading?
The book should cover a basic idea about what the elements of modern synthetic theory are and briefly what are the conclusions of the theory.

Feel free to suggest edits.

Comment: Please add details outlined in the [tag-wiki for book-recommendation.](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info).

Comment: @WYSIWYG Is it okay ? I don't have much to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no modern book of evolutionary biology that is not about the modern synthesis. So what you are looking for is just an introductory book to evolutionary biology.

I think the 2 most common introductory textbook to evolutionary biology are:

- ["Evolution: Making Sense of Life" by Carl Zimmer](https://www.amazon.ca/Evolution-Making-Sense-Carl-Zimmer/dp/1936221551/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1466588612&sr=8-2&keywords=evolution%20making%20sense)
- ["Evolution" by Futuyma](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0878931872)

Note by the way that one can find recommendation on population genetics (subfield of evolution) [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/book-recommendation-on-population-evolutionary-genetics).