# Linkage Disequilibrium - What does it mean when D < 0?

Tags: genetics, genetic-linkage

What does it mean when you have a situation where your `D<0`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider two bi-allelic loci, A and B with alleles `A1`, `A2` for A and `B1`, `B2` for B. Negative values for D means that `A1` is more often associated with `B2` than expected. Similarly, `A2` is more often associated with `B1` than expected.

More info on [Wikiedpia > Linkage Disequilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium) or on any intro book to population genetics (see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/books-on-population-or-evolutionary-genetics) for recommendations). If there is anything in particular you do not about the definition of LD, feel free to ask a question by highlighting what is unclear to you.