# Recommendations for textbooks on statistical and quantitative genetics, and genetic epidemiology

Tags: population-genetics, epidemiology, biostatistics, quantitative-genetics, gwas

I'm looking for a textbook on statistical genetics, quantitative genetics, association mapping, and genetic epidemiology. My interests include, but are not limited to, complex trait analysis, and the mathematical and statistical aspects of these subjects.

I've found a lot of books, below are some that I'm considering:

- "Genetics and Analysis of Quantitative Traits" by M. Lynch et al. ([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0878934812))
- "Introduction to Quantitative Genetics" by D. Falconer et al. ([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582243025))
- "Statistical Genetics: Gene Mapping Through Linkage and Association" by B. Neale et al. ([amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Genetics-Mapping-Through-Association-ebook/dp/B008ZJKSP0/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1517483525&sr=1-1&keywords=statistical+genetics))
- "Statistical Genetics of Quantitative Traits: Linkage, Maps and QTL" by R. Wu et al. ([amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Genetics-Quantitative-Traits-Statistics-ebook/dp/B0017T2ZRO/ref=sr_1_2?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1517483525&sr=1-2&keywords=statistical+genetics))

I haven't found anyone else posting this question. There are discussions about population genetics textbooks, but these books have limited information about quantitative genetics, etc.

If anyone has a favorite book, comments about the books above, or anything, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Another promising book:

- "The Statistics of Gene Mapping" by D. O Siegmund ([amazon link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistics-Gene-Mapping-Author-published/dp/B006DNTRCA/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1518076065&sr=1-4&keywords=the+statistics+of+gene+mapping&dpID=41VWoModXfL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch))

Comment: Related: [Books on population or evolutionary genetics?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/books-on-population-or-evolutionary-genetics)

Answer (score 1):

For statistical genetics, take a look at:

```
Likelihood, Bayesian, and MCMC Methods in Quantitative Genetics. Daniel 
Sorenson and Daniel Gianola. (2002. Springer).
```

Warning: heavy on math (calculus). If that doesn't scare you, it's excellent guide to non-frequentist statistical methods applied to problems in genetics.

Comment: It kind of looks like all but the last chapter are about Bayesian statistics, so you might as well read a different book on that, and then another book on quantitative genetics.

Comment: Actually, chapters 5, 6, 7, and 8 (25% of the chapters) cover Bayesian statistics. Chapters 13-16 (another 25%) cover applied quantitative methods. Not sure what book you were looking at.

Comment: I see, part IV of the book, chapters 13-16 are about quantitative genetics. Still, chapters 1-12 are about Bayesian statistics and inference, so a really small portion of the book is about quantitative genetics. Looks interesting nonetheless, especially for someone who is unfamiliar with Bayesian statistics and would like to get into it.